# How to increase kernel poll rate for accelerometer?

Tags: linux, kernel, polling

I'm using the hwmon/mxc_mma8451.c module to access an accelerometer.  Using `/sys/devices/virtual/input/input0/poll` I can change the polling rate to some degree... if I set a larger millisecond value the polling becomes slower.  However, I cannot seem to get below around 30ms per poll, despite the device driver source apparently allowing as low as 1ms per poll.  The accelerometer itself supports 800Hz sample rate, so that is not the bottleneck.  When I write a value of 1 to the above file, I see each sample occurs either 30ms or 60ms from the previous sample, so it is not even consistent.  However, even 30ms is unacceptably slow at it is only 33Hz.

The kernel source for the module clearly shows that I should be able to use a value of 1:

```
#define POLL_INTERVAL_MIN       1
#define POLL_INTERVAL_MAX       500
#define POLL_INTERVAL           100     /* msecs */
...
mma8451_idev->poll_interval = POLL_INTERVAL;
mma8451_idev->poll_interval_min = POLL_INTERVAL_MIN;
mma8451_idev->poll_interval_max = POLL_INTERVAL_MAX;
```

I'm not familiar with exactly how Linux does this kind of polling, but this system has a 10ms tick, so even if sampling with ticks, why is it taking 3 or 6 ticks per sample and nothing else?  Is there some kernel parameter somewhere else that is throttling how fast polling can occur?

Linux kernel version is 3.14.28 for IMX28 (ARM) if that makes any difference.  This is the version available for the device in question, so I can't just up and use a different/newer one.

Comment: There is no such driver in the kernel. The closest one is `drivers/input/misc/mma8450.c`. Have you tried it?

Comment: @0andriy oh that's interesting. i have both.  guess i'll try that one and see if it differs.

Comment: Or even inside IIO framework `drivers/iio/accel/mma8452.c`.

Comment: Looks like 8451 is supported by latter one. And it sounds promising since IIO framework is specifically designed for sensor devices like that accelerometer.

Comment: @0andriy don't have mma84* in iio/accel... maybe kernel version is too old?

Comment: Just for refrence: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/iio/accel/mma8452.c (v3.16 is the first I see the driver in, so you have *ancient* kernel)